# Question regarding (possibly) the exterior product in $\Bbb R^n$ and a unit normal vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm at the moment self-studying about differential forms and I would like to first write down some definitions and results I find relevant for the task (because I couldn't find the proper translation from Croatian to English, so maybe some description wil help here) and then the task itself and my thoughts.

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition } 19.4}}$

> A set $D\subset\Bbb R^n$ is called a (smooth) $k$ cell if there is an injective map $\varphi\in C^1(U,\Bbb R^n),$ where $I^k\subset U$ s. t. $\varphi(I^k)=D$ and $\nabla\varphi(x)$ is of the maximum range $k,\forall x\in U$. The map $\varphi_{\mid I^k}$ is called a parametrization of $D$.

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition: }}}$

> Let $I=(i_1,\ldots,i_k)$ be an ordered tuple of elements of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.We define a function $dx_I:(\Bbb R^n)^k\to\Bbb R$ as $dx_I(a^1,\ldots,a^k)=\det A_I,$ where $A_I\in M_k(\Bbb R)$ is a matrix whose $r$-th row is the $i_r$-th row of the matrix $A=(a^1,\ldots,a^k)$.

If I understood this correctly,  $A_I=\begin{bmatrix}e_{i_1}^T\\\vdots\\e_{i_k}^T\end{bmatrix}\cdot A.$

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{note: }}}$

> Let $I$ and $J$ be two increasing ordered $k$-tuples of indices. Then, $$dx_I(e^{j_1},\ldots,e^{j_k})=\begin{cases}1,&\text{ if } I=J,\\0,&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
> Due to the properties of a determinant, $dx_I$ are alternating functions and they span the space of all alternating $k$-multilinear functions:

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{theorem } 18.1:}}$

> Suppose $M:(\Bbb R^n)^k\to\Bbb R$ is an alternating $k$-multilinear function. Then, $$M=\sum_{[I]}\alpha_Idx_I,$$ where $I=(i_1,\ldots,i_k), \alpha_i=M(e^{i_1},\ldots,e^{i_k})$ and $[I]$ says we sum over all increasing $k$ tuples of indices.

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{theorem }18.3}}$

> Let $k\le n$ and suppose we are given some matrices $A\in M_{kn}(\Bbb R),B\in M_{nk}(\Bbb R)$. Then $$\det AB=\sum_{[I]}(\det A_I^T)\det B_I.$$

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{theorem }18.4}}$

> Suppose $P$ is a $k$ dimensional parallelepiped in $\Bbb R^n, k\le n$ spanned by the vectors $a^1,\ldots,a^k.$ Denote $A=(a^1,\ldots, a^k)\in M_{nk}(\Bbb R)$. Then the volume equals $$p(P)=\sqrt{\det A^TA.}$$

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition } 20.1}}$

> Differential $k$-form $\mu$ on $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ is a map $\mu: U\to\Lambda^k(\Bbb R^n),$ where $\Lambda^k(\Bbb R^n)$ denotes the set of all alternating $k$-multilinear functions on $\Bbb R^n$.

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{lemma }20.14:}}$

> Suppose $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_k$ are differential $1$-forms on $\Bbb R^n$ given by $$\omega_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}u_j,i=1,\ldots,k
> $$ Denote $A=(a_{ij})$. Then $$\omega_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\omega_k=\det A du_1\wedge\ldots\wedge u_n.$$

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition :}}}$

> We define the form of the area of a surface for a $k$- cell $D\subset\Bbb R^n$ as a $k$-differential form given by $$dA=\sum_{[I]}n_Idx_I,$$ where the functions $n_I$ are defined as follows:
>
> Let $I=(i_1,\ldots,i_k),x\in D$ and let $\varphi:U\to\Bbb R^n$ be a parametrization of a $k$-cell, $x=\varphi(u)$. Then $$n_I(x)=\frac1\Delta\det\nabla\varphi_I(u)=\frac1\Delta\frac{\partial(\varphi_{i_1},\ldots,\varphi_{i_k})}{\partial(u_1,\ldots,u_k)}(u),$$ where $$\Delta=\sqrt{\det\nabla\varphi(u)^T\nabla\varphi(u)}=\sqrt{\sum_{[I]}(\det\nabla\varphi_I(u))^2}.$$

$\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{Task:}}}$

> Suppose $\varphi:U\to\Bbb R^n$ is a parametrization of an $n-1$-dimensional cell in $\Bbb R^n$. Let's define a vector $\boldsymbol N$ on the cell by components $$N_i(\varphi(u))=\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}\Delta\det\frac{\partial(\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_{i-1},\varphi_{i+1},\ldots,\varphi_n)}{\partial (u_1,\ldots, u_{n-1})}(u)\tag 1$$ Show that $\boldsymbol N(\varphi(u))$ is perpendicular to every vector $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_k},k=1,\ldots,n-1$ and, therefore, a unit normal vector at the point $\varphi(u)$ of the cell.

**My thoughts:**

I've read a bit more about the generalized cross-product- the exterior product, in higher-dimensions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4089495/942722), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/980077/942722) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260563/942722). I think we might write
$$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_{n-1}}=\begin{vmatrix}e_1&e_2&\ldots&e_n\\\frac{\partial\varphi_1}{\partial u_1}&\frac{\partial\varphi_2}{\partial u_1}&\ldots&\frac{\partial\varphi_n}{\partial u_1}\\\frac{\partial\varphi_1}{\partial u_2}&\frac{\partial\varphi_2}{\partial u_2}&\ldots&\frac{\partial\varphi_n}{\partial u_2}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\frac{\partial\varphi_1}{\partial u_{n-1}}&\frac{\partial\varphi_2}{\partial u_{n-1}}&\ldots&\frac{\partial\varphi_n}{\partial u_{n-1}}\end{vmatrix}$$

and then the component $N_i$ should be the coefficient in front of $e_i$ in the Laplace expansion by the first row and then take the wedge product with the LHS $$\left(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_{n-1}}\right)\wedge\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_k}=0,k=1,\ldots,n-1$$

. However, I'm not able to prove $\boldsymbol N(\varphi(u))\perp\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_k},k=1,\ldots,n-1$ rigorously. I think I might use the $\boldsymbol{\text{lemma } 20.14}$ and properties of the wedge product of differentials to manipulate with the determinant, but I'm a bit lost.

Does anyone have any advice on solving this task?

If I wasn't precise enough, I'll appreciate if you point out. (:

I apologize for possible mistakes and for the lengthy post.

Comment: The advice is to boil down this post to the bare minimum and looking at $\mathbf{N}(\varphi(u))\bot\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u_k}$ in small dimensions, $n=2,3$ and so on.

Comment: @KurtG., I think I should leave the last part, but I'm not sure for the rest. What would you advise me to delete so as to not lose the context or maybe address something else to show my background?

Comment: Most of the stuff you wrote is fairly standard but you do not have to delete anyhing. What I mean is you should work out what you want to show in the simple low dimensional cases. I cannot help thinking that it is just the overwhelming amount of notation that has led you to post this question.